# I used this formula and if nothing is in the cells I get a #value! until its populated, can you tell me how to keep it from giving me the error?

Tags: worksheet-function

I used this formula and if nothing is in the cells I get a #value! until its populated, can you tell me how to keep it from giving me the error?

```
=IF(P30<>"","10","")+IF(P31<>"","10","")+IF(P32<>"","10","")+IF(P33<>"","10","")+IF(P34<>"","10","")
```

Comment: Please read https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what do you expect it to say?

Answer (score 0):

Classic solution to all such problems:

`=IFERROR( <orignal formula>, "Formula failed!" )`